# Hosted app status dashboard

Tags: saas, health-monitoring

I wish to provide a status dashboard to users of my SAAS internet application similar to the status dashboards provided by Google and Amazon.

Does anyone know of a ready-made 3rd party hosted service supporting such an interface?

Google example:

http://www.google.com/appsstatus#hl=en

Amazon Example:

http://status.aws.amazon.com

Comment: https://statushub.io/ is out there now, it's the only fully turnkey hosted status dashboard I've seen. Haven't used it but it looks decent if you don't want to host the dashboard yourself.

Answer (score 3):

[Stashboard](http://www.stashboard.org) is an open-source status dashboard hosted on Google App Engine. I created Stashboard this summer for Twilio's API status dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

[Geckoboard](http://Geckoboard.com) might be worth to use it.